# Higher z-index div doesn't hide lower z-index click events: event propagation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation, event-propagation

I've read, and read, but I'm still missing something.

I have an click event that displays a div

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    |
|         [ Click Here ]   [ Another Click Event ]   |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

After selecting "click here" a div covers "another click event" but one can still select "another click event" even if one doesn't see it.

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                        +------------------------+  |
|         [ Click Here ] |                        |  |
+------------------------|                        |--+
                         |                        |
                         +------------------------+



$("#another-click-event").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#another-click-event").toggleClass("highlight");
    $("#another-click-event2").toggleClass("show-create-cost2");
}); 

$("#click-here").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#click-here").toggleClass("highlight");
    $("#click-here2").toggle("slide");
});
```

After #click-here is selected #click-here2 slides out. Good.

But #another-click-event can still be selected. Not good.

Why doesn't stopPropagation work?

**EDIT**

Attached is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/84jg0q9k/2/

However !?! the fiddle is working as it's supposed to. And yet ... it's simply a copy and paste?

TL/DR - The code works. It's not a stopPropagation error. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Fiddle? I hate looking at static graphs and illustrations.

Comment: Try stopping propagation on the click event of the div hiding [another click event] (click-here2)?

Comment: Please replace the ASCII art with relevant HTML and CSS, so that we can re-produce your issue.

Comment: i kinda like the ASCII art =\. But yeah, a fiddle would present the problem more clearly

Comment: Created a fiddle. But wouldn't you know - it works in the fiddle. And everything is a simple copy and paste.  Very annoying.

Comment: AS you said, the fiddle works with normal behaviour. Maybe you have got a css or a javascript that enter in conflicts. `pointer-events` css property can make your code problematic. Read that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude - thx. I think I'll take the simple route: and that's to rebuild piece by piece. There's some gremlin somewhere and its not a stopPropagation error.

Comment: @Mayo FYI, you don't have `.show-create-cost2` declared in CSS. Not a problem if that class serves as a flag to indicate a state, but it is if it's a class for presentation purposes.

Comment: @zer00ne - my bad. It exists. I didn't copy it over from my prototype.

Comment: try event binding like this  $("body").on('click','#item-total-sales', function(e){});